# JSON Schema oneof without required

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema

In `JSON Schema` draft 7 or 8 what is the right way to say that we want optionally either one of the attributes but not both. I can construct with `required` keyword, but then you have to include either one of the required attributes. This is what I can think of, is this correct?

In this example I'm trying to validate `field_1` is required and we want either one of `field_2`, `field_3` or none of them. (see examples)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-08/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "field_1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "field_2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "field_3": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "field_1"
  ],
  "oneof": [
    {
      "properties": [
        "field_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": [
        "field_3"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "examples": [
    {
      "field_1": "1",
      "field_2": "2"
    },
    {
      "field_1": "1",
      "field_3": "3"
    },
    {
      "field_1": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *[EDITED - SEE THIRD SOLUTION BELOW]*

### Solution 1 - At least one, but not both (verbose)

I would add an `allOf` with a nested `oneOf`:

```
{
  ...
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {"required": ["field_2"]},
        {"required": ["field_3"]}
      ],
    },
    {
      "not": {
        "required": ["field_2", "field_3"]
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

This requires that one of the two fields are present, but not both.

---

### Solution 2 - At least one, but not both

I think this can be further simplified by using just the `oneOf`:

```
{
  ...
  "oneOf": [
    {"required": ["field_2"]},
    {"required": ["field_3"]}
  ],
  ...
}
```

- If neither are there, then these will both fail, and the `oneOf` fails.
- If one is there, then the `oneOf` passes.
- If both are there, then both of these will pass, and the `oneOf` fails.

Yeah, this is better.  Looking at what you had, I think this is what you were trying to do, so you were *really* close!

---

### Solution 3 - At most one

To pass when neither field are present you need the first solution, but change the `allOf` to an `anyOf`:

```
{
  ...
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {"required": ["field_2"]},
        {"required": ["field_3"]}
      ],
    },
    {
      "not": {
        "required": ["field_2", "field_3"]
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

- If neither are there, then the `not` subschema will pass, and the `anyOf` passes.
- If one is there, then the `oneOf` subschema will pass, and the `anyOf` passes.
- If both are there, then

  - both of the `oneOf` subschemas will pass, so the `oneOf` fails
  - the `not` subschema will fail
  - so the `anyOf` fails

You can test these solutions [here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/m4Di2)

Comment: one of my requirement is that it should pass even if neither `field_2` or `field_3` are present, I dont see second solution passes this. And in your first solution I feel like two conditions in the `allof` block are contradicting. Any comments...

Comment: I've edited the answer to accommodate the "neither" requirement.

Comment: thanks your third solutions works fine. Bit verbose though, dependencies solution from Jason is also quite handy. I realised that there multiple ways to achieve this.

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve most things with JSON Schema 

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple more options to add to @gregdennis's answer.

## Dependencies

This is a great use case for the `dependencies` keyword. This says, "if there is a "field_2" there can't be a "field_3" and, "if there is a "field_3" there can't be a "field_2". If neither "field_2" or "field_3" exist, no constraints apply and the schema passes.

```
"dependencies": {
  "field_2": { "not": { "required": ["field_3"] } },
  "field_3": { "not": { "required": ["field_2"] } }
}
```

## maxProperties

This one is a bit hacky, but it has the benefit of being a one liner. If "field_1" is required and only one of "field_2" or "field_2" are allowed, there can not be more than two properties present in this object. Beware, this solution might be more clever than it's worth. Because this constraint works indirectly, it can be lead to maintenance difficulties in the future.

```
"maxProperties": 2
```

## if/then

This is just a more verbose version of the `dependencies` options, but might be more descriptive for someone reading the schema.

```
"allOf": [
  {
    "if": { "required": ["field_2"] },
    "then": { "not": { "required": ["field_3"] } }
  },
  {
    "if": { "required": ["field_3"] },
    "then": { "not": { "required": ["field_2"] } }
  }
]
```

Comment: Awesome, I really like the dependencies solution. I believe it clearly pass the message. allof, oneof solutions are quite bit verbose.

Comment: Note that for draft 2019-09 and later, `dependencies` in this usage has been changed to `dependentProperties`

Comment: @gregsdennis thanks for the update, I just check the [changelog](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html) is it `dependentSchemas` instead of `dependentProperties`?

Comment: There is no `dependentProperties` whatsoever. `dependencies` has been replaced by `dependentSchemas` and `dependentRequired` keywords. See Appendix A of https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to try to figure this out for 3 fields where field 1 is also optional. Doing so revealed @gregdennis's answer to **Solution 3** was slightly more than it needed to be, this accomplishes the same goal as there is no need to check for required single values as neither are required.

```
{
  ...
  "not": {
    "required": ["field_2", "field_3"]
  } 
  ...
}
```

To do this for 3, it looks like:

```
{
  ...
  "not": {
    "anyOf": [{
      "required": ["field_1", "field_2", "field_3"]
    },
    {
      "required": ["field_1", "field_2"]
    },
    {
      "required": ["field_2", "field_3"]
    },
    {
      "required": ["field_1", "field_3"]
    }]
  }
  ...
}
```

As you add more fields, this obviously becomes less useful. So a better solution with room to go to N is the following:

```
{
  ...
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {"required": ["field_1"]},
        {"required": ["field_2"]},
        {"required": ["field_3"]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "not": {
        "anyOf": [
          {"required": ["field_1"]},
          {"required": ["field_2"]},
          {"required": ["field_3"]}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

You can play with it [here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/qOcnB).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "field_1": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {

      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "field_2": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": ["field_2"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "field_3": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": ["field_3"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ],
  "required": [
    "field_1"
  ]
}
```

As stated in [this book](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof): "oneOf: (XOR) Must be valid against **exactly one** of the subschemas".

1. I added the field_1 to the "main" schema and marked this field as required.
2. I described three subschemas.

- The first schema without required fields.
- The second schema with required "field_2" field.
- The third schema with required "field_3" field.

3. For all subschemas I set the "additionalProperties" in the value *false*.